# Ajax Get Request with multiple data parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have issue sending multiple parameters data with ajax GET request.
Can anyone help?

My code is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "test.aspx/GetRecord",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: 'DateFrom=' + DateFrom + '&DateTo=' + DateTo + '&Pro=' + Pro + '&pageIndex=' + _pageNo + '&pageSize=' + $("select[id$='ddl_page_size']").val() + '',
  success: onsuccessGetRecord,
  error: function () {

  }
});
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Do any of your variables have spaces within them?

Answer (score 0):

Well the correct syntax for multiple data is:

data: {status: status, name: name , etc : etc},

so it would be like:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/activity_save.php",
                data: {status: status, name: name , etc : etc},
                sucess: on..................
```

can also check here for more reference.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hope this helps

Comment: `data` can be given both as URL encoded string *or* object; the latter is more convenient but it's not the only correct way.